# Trying to Send Email Using Alexa and AWS SES. Email will send however Alexa will return and Error

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-ses

I am writing an Alexa Skill where one of the functions is to request to send an email to a user using AWS SES.

When the utterance is said to send the email, the email will send however Alexa will always reply 'There was a problem with the requested skill's response'.

I have tested to make sure the 'getEmail' intent itself is working and it is. 
I have also tried moving the function within the intent but this has the same results.

This is the function to send the email using SES which seems to be working:

function sendEmail (event, context, callback){

```
    var params = {
    Destination: {
        ToAddresses: ["xyz@gmail.com"]
    },
    Message: {
        Body: {
            Text: { Data: "Hi. Here is your email"

            }

        },

        Subject: { Data: "Here is an email"

        }
    },
    Source: "abc@gmail.com"
};


 ses.sendEmail(params, function (err, data) {
      callback(null, {err: err, data: data});
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        context.fail(err);


    } else {

        console.log(data);
        context.succeed(event);

    }

});
```

}

Here is the intent which call the sendEmail() function.

```
'getEmail': function () {

    sendEmail();
    var bodyTemplate1 = new Alexa.templateBuilders.BodyTemplate1Builder();

    var template1 = bodyTemplate1.setTitle("email").setTextContent(makeRichText("email")).setBackgroundImage(makeImage(image)).build();

    this.response.speak("Your email has been sent").renderTemplate(template1).shouldEndSession(true);
    this.emit(':responseReady');

},
```

When I run this I would like for the email to send to the the device and Alexa to just say "Your Email has been sent". At the moment it is just the email that is sending and the device saying "There was a problem with the requested skill's response"

[Here is the error message from AWS Cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLCCU.png)

Comment: Do you need `this.response.speak("");` - won't that just clear what you're setting on the line above? Anyway, do you have any errors in the console. If you've deployed to AWS Lambda you should check your CloudWatch logs for any error messages. There's an example of what you're doing with the templates [here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/blob/1.x/Readme.md#display-interface).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry that 'this.response.speak("");' had just been left in as I was playing around with it. I have added the error from cloudwatch above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at logs, your `callback(null, {err: err, data: data});` is the issue here. From the code that you posted, `callback` doesn't exist (will be `undefined`). It doesn't look like you need that there so you can remove it.

[AWS SDK - `SES.sendEmail`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#sendEmail-property)

The "callback" is just your function that's passed as the second argument.